# JavaFx - Kotlin - How to get Item value from ListView?

Tags: xml, kotlin, javafx

So I have a basic "app", basically all it does it loads users from a cvs files.

Now I am dysplaing these user onto a ListView. However I can't figure out how to get the value (The users are stored as Strings in the ListView) and either print it in the console or do something else with it.

So this Is my Code for storing the users. It just saves the User string into a mutableList and adds it to the ListView.

```
fun addUsser(name: String, age: Int, date: LocalDate) {
    val user= Uzivatel(name, age, date);
    userList.add(user);

    usersListView.items.add(0, user.toString());
}
```

I had tried using **usersListView.selectionMode** and **usersListView.selectionMode.selectedItem** etc.. however I can't get it to work

Comment: This just sounds like the wrong approach. Your `ListView` should use the actual `User` object in its backing items list, not strings.

Comment: I had tried it, but because of how my program is structured I can't use User object in the ListView.

Comment: Sorry, that makes no sense. Why can’t you use it in the list view?

Comment: As noted, it doesn't really make sense why you can't use a `ListView<User>`. That is the proper solution (if not `User` then some other data class). Please clarify why that doesn't work for you, preferably with a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Well the reason I am not using ListView<User>, is because I have a code that reads data from a list and I can't change it to read it from ListView, I just have the ListView to show that the there is some data loaded.

Comment: Why not have your `ListView` be backed by the `userList` instance then? If that's not an `ObservableList` then you can wrap it with `FXCollections.observableList(userList)`.